# How to set up SAMBA on ubuntu with a 2tb drive connected to my dlink router?

Tags: networking, server, mount, hard-drive, samba

I tried mounting the network drive on all 5 computers in my home with smbfs: 
`//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /media/Shared_drive cifs guest 0 0`

It works but I just think samba might be more secure. I have some guest users on those computers and they can access that drive too which I don't want. I only want specific users able to see that drive connected to my router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have some extra garbage in /etc/fstab - the string `to your /etc/fstab` after the last `0` does not belong there.

If your router allows you to password-protect your share that do that and consult [the official ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders) about how to store that password in your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: oops, i fixed it here. I had the right stuff in my /etc/fstab though, just that I put the tilde in the wrong place here